# Aura Lightning Component helper js file change doesn't reflect on client side

Tags: lightning-aura-components, deployment, helper

I've made changes in the existing Lightning Component helper js file using the Developer Console and saved it. But those changes are not reflecting when I'm trying to use the object associated with it. Still the old JS code is visible when I check it in the browser sources.

Do I have to do anything in order to deploy the changes I made. I'm using sandbox environment. I'm new to Salesforce and still learning. Hope my question is a not a silly one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on Setup -> Edit Page , it will redirect to Lightning app builder , you can 'Save' the component there and click on 'Back' to return to previous page.This should render the component with the latest updates you made in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Lightning uses caching by default, so sometimes the browser takes a bit to catch up. To fix the problem, disable caching in Setup > Session Settings > Caching, and uncheck *Enable secure and persistent browser caching to improve performance*. Alternatively, consider using a "hard refresh" by using Ctrl-F5, Shift-F5, or whatever other combination your browser uses to "skip the cache and refresh."