# Why are my Lightning Page Layout changes not commited?

Tags: lightning, page-layout

I have made some changed to my Lightning Page using the Lightning editor (Setting > Edit Page), Saved and Activated the page (set the page as my org wide default).

But whenever I return to the page, the changes are not there. I have verified the App, Record Type and Profile land on the same page I have edited (there is only one page for that object anyway).

Can someone advise why the page changes aren't being reflected?

Comment: Can you check if this helps- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/302983/aura-lightning-component-helper-js-file-change-doesnt-reflect-on-client-side/302984#302984 ?

Comment: So isn't related to any custom components, I'm merely adding new tabs to the record detail page.